# Is it a wrong exercise in Pinter's Algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra

It is the exercise *D6* from *chapter 8* of Pinter's Algebra.

> (I'm supposed to prove it.) Let $a$ and $b$ be cycles (not necessarily disjoint). If $a^2 = b^2$, then $a = b$.

Am I correct that it is a wrong proposition? Consider $a = (1324)$, $b = (1423)$. Then $a^2 = (12)(34) = b^2$, but $a \neq b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my second edition Pinter book, the problem is stated for cycles of odd length. Quoting page 88 (emphasis mine),

> Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be cycles **of odd length** (not disjoint). Prove that if $\alpha^2 = \beta^2$, then $\alpha=\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use any two transpositions that are not equal, such as $(1 2)$ and $(3 4)$, whose squares are both equal to $1$.

Is this a true/false question?

Comment: No, this question is supposed to be proved.